# Can I open Tumblr bookmarklet in different windows?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, tumblr

Code for Tumblr's bookmarklet:

```
javascript: var d = document,
w = window,
e = w.getSelection,
k = d.getSelection,
x = d.selection,
s = (e ? e() : (k) ? k() : (x ? x.createRange().text : 0)),
f = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share',
l = d.location,
e = encodeURIComponent,
p = '?v=3&u=' + e(l.href) + '&t=' + e(d.title) + '&s=' + e(s),
u = f + p;
try {
if (!/^(.*\.)?tumblr[^.]*$/.test(l.host)) throw (0);
tstbklt();
}     
catch (z) {
a = function () {
    if (!w.open(u, 't', 'toolbar=0,resizable=0,status=1,width=450,height=430')) l.href = u;
};
if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) setTimeout(a, 0);
else a();
}
void(0)
```

Hard to explain, but here goes:

I use the Tumblr bookmarklet a lot on Flickr, but there's one thing that always annoys me: if you try to open multiple share windows, it just loads the pages in the same new window.

I'm just wondering if there's any way to edit this code to allow me to open multiple windows...

I hope I explained that clearly...thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `w.open(u, 't', ...)` to `w.open(u, '_blank', ...)`.

The second argument to [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) is the *target* (or *window name*).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/HvTuv/).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so so so so much!! You saved me so much time, haha. Thanks times a million!